# Set default Form value without changing page parameters

Tags: java, forms, wicket

How do I set default values of `Form<BgwElasticSearchFields>` when the log review page is loaded? Basically before loading the page I need to set the default values for `Bic` and `dtTo`, `dtFrom`. I tried the `setDefaultModel` but I didn't quite understand it. Any help? Thanks!

```
@Override
protected Form<ElasticSearchFields> getSearchForm() {
    Form<ElasticSearchFields> logSearchForm = new Form<ElasticSearchFields>("searchFields",
            new CompoundPropertyModel<>(searchFields)) {

    logSearchForm.add(new DateTextField("dtTo", new PropertyModel<>(searchFields, "dtTo"), "yyyy-MM-dd").setRequired(true));
    logSearchForm.add(new DateTextField("dtFrom", new PropertyModel<>(searchFields, "dtFrom"), "yyyy-MM-dd").setRequired(true));

    List<String> bics = Arrays.stream(Bic.values())
            .map(Bic::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    logSearchForm.add(new DropDownChoice<>(
            "bic",
            new PropertyModel<>(searchFields, "bic"),
            bics).setNullValid(true).setRequired(false));

    return logSearchForm;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `setDefaultModel` and it didn't work. It worked perfectly with `setDefaultModelObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the default values in `searchFields`. After successful submit Wicket will override them with the values sent by the browser.

Comment: But will they appear as soon as I load the page? Because what I'm trying to achieve is to prefill the forms with needed information. F.e. Form `Bic` consists of various countries bics. When loading the page from country X, user would have prefilled Bic field with X country bic. Same with date, instead of having it empty as it is now, user would have it set to current date automatically after loading the page.

Comment: Yes! Try it and see for yourself! :-)